# Python error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lowercase'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples, pyodbc

(I'm quite an amateur here, so go easy!). I can't seem to get past this error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 31, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lowercase'
```

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import pyodbc

#connect to SQL Server database
db=pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=NotAChance;DATABASE=theCan;UID=HAHA;PWD=NotGonnaTell;")

#set the database cursor
c=db.cursor()

#SQL for getting PIDs that have feature classes locked
c.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT sde.SDE_table_locks.*,
sde.SDE_process_information.start_time,
sde.SDE_process_information.owner,
sde.SDE_process_information.nodename,
sde.SDE_process_information.direct_connect,
sde.SDE_table_registry.table_name
FROM sde.SDE_table_locks
INNER JOIN sde.SDE_table_registry ON sde.SDE_table_locks.registration_id = sde.SDE_table_registry.registration_id
WHERE (sde.SDE_table_registry.table_name) Like '%%'""")

#Create a list to dump PIDs in to, so we can weed down to unique ones
mylist = []

#Loop through the PIDs 
for (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) in c.fetchall():

    #add the PID that needs to be killed to a list
    mylist.append(b)
    #print (mylist)

#weed the list of PIDs down to just the unique PIDs
pids_to_kill = dict(map(lambda i: (i,1),mylist)).keys()

arcpy.AddMessage(pids_to_kill)

#reset the cursor
c=db.cursor()

#loop through the unique PIDs and delete each lock record
for i in pids_to_kill:
    c.execute("DELETE FROM sde.SDE_table_locks WHERE sde.SDE_table_locks.registration_id = " + str(i))
    c=db.cursor()

#commit the changes
db.commit()

#disconnect
db.close()
```

I'm having trouble understanding the issue it's having with my tuple. I'm not doing anything with .lower() anywhere in the code.

I'm using Python 2.7 and running this in ArcGIS 10.5 (python window, as well as in a script tool). This could potentially go in the GIS Stack Exchange, but I'm not sure it's particularly GIS-related.

Comment: What is the *full* traceback? Not just the last line.

Comment: Try `arcpy.AddMessage(str(pids_to_kill))` instead of `arcpy.AddMessage(pids_to_kill)`.

Comment: I updated my question with the full error message-

Comment: The error is being thrown by the line:
  `for (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) in c.fetchall():`

Comment: (Changing to  `arcpy.AddMessage(str(pids_to_kill))` didn't resolve the issue.)

Comment: You're using `c` for your database connection cursor and then overwriting is with `for (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)`. Try using `cursor=db.cursor()` maybe?

Comment: Thanks @FlipperPA: I think this was probably the cause. I can't account for why the  same script worked fine for several years, and then suddenly stopped working now. However, when I changed the variable `c` to something else `x`, it did work. Admittedly, I was making a lot of alterations to my code without really 'controlling' them tightly, so it's possible something else I did resolved the issue too. I need to go back and try to re-run the code with just this one alteration to determine if it was indeed the culprit.